# Get value from key within object key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an object called `val` that looks like this:

```js
{
    "outer": [
        {
            "key": "A",
            "value": {
                "70": 14,
                "84": 22
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "B",
            "value": {
                "70": 9,
                "84": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "C",
            "value": {
                "70": 83,
                "84": 135
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can call this:

```js
console.log(val.outer.find(x => x.key === 'A').value)
{"70": 14, "84": 22}
```

Is there a way I can print the value relating to "84"?

So for example, I'd like to log where `Key = A` and `Value Key = 84.`

Comment: `/* ... */.value[84]`?

Comment: you can access object properties like an array, using `["what you need"]` as selector

Comment: I guess you meant `val.outer.find`

Answer (score 1):

Simply access the value relating to "84" by brackets:

```js
val = {
    "outer": [
        {
            "key": "A",
            "value": {
                "70": 14,
                "84": 22
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "B",
            "value": {
                "70": 9,
                "84": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "C",
            "value": {
                "70": 83,
                "84": 135
            }
        }
    ]
}
console.log(val.outer.find(x => x.key === 'A').value['84']);//print 22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the object as an array and call `obj['84']` or `obj[84]`:

```js
var val = {
    "outer": [
        {
            "key": "A",
            "value": {
                "70": 14,
                "84": 22
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "B",
            "value": {
                "70": 9,
                "84": 11
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "C",
            "value": {
                "70": 83,
                "84": 135
            }
        }
    ]
};

console.log(val.outer.find(x => x.key === 'A').value['84']);
```